# Swipe back and forward on navigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Each UIViewController, starting with rootViewController uses  [self.navigationController pushViewController nextView] to push new views. Swipe works fine.

How can I implement the same behavior for the swipe forward? I more exactly, how I keep the UIViewController after popped with swipe back or back button, so I can add it again in case of swipe forward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keep track of your view controllers, you could do the following:

- Add an instance variable (as a strong property) `nextViewController` to all your view controllers
- Whenever you push a new view controller, set `nextViewController` to the pushed view controller
- Now, whenever the user swipes forward, you just push the `nextViewController`. But, first check for `nil`.  If `currentViewController.nextViewController = nil` you know that the user has never navigated beyond this point, and you handle appropriately.  You could just ignore the swipe forward, or you could send the user a message.

To handle the swipe itself:

- Just add a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to each view controller's `view`.
- Then, when your swipe method is called, check the gesture recognizer's `direction` property.  If it was a forward swipe, push the `nextViewController` as described above.

Comment: but the view won't be destroyed by the default back behavior?

Comment: No, because the nextViewController property retains it, that is, as long as you implement it as a property and make sure to retain.

Comment: What if I want to build a breadcrumbs bar at the bottom? Like big dots, where the user can go directly to enabled views. What should I use? Or is this a completely new matter? I think maybe a tab bar can work. What you think?

Comment: If you have 5 view controllers or less, a tab bar controller sounds to me like the best choice.  It implements precisely the functionality you want, and you could do without the navigation controller.  But, a tab bar controller is limited to 5 visible tabs.  Any more view controllers would just appear as a list in the last tab, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have 7, actually. I think the controller I want is the UIPageControl. I'm trying to figure out how to use it together with my navigation controller. Again. Thanks.

Comment: Turned out that navigation controller + UIPageControl don't play nice together. I ended up using the exact solution you proposed. Thank you again.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  When working with a navigation controller, the current view controller should change only by pushing or popping.  If a UIPageControl were to override that behavior, you could run into trouble.

Comment: To build a breadcrumbs bar, you could add a UIBarButtonItem to the toolbar.  Create the bar button item using `initWithCustomView:` and creating your own view showing the 7 dots, or whatever is appropriate.  If the view controllers are always in the same order, you create a different button in each one, with the corresponding dot brighter than the others.  If not, you could update the bar button item thru the nav controller delegate, implementing `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`. Just make sure to keep a pointer (maybe an ivar) to the button item, so u can update it.

Comment: When I tried implementing something similar with a pan gesture recognizer I got `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '<Speech_Drill.SlidingNavigationController: 0x10a810c00> is pushing the same view controller instance (<Speech_Drill.MainVC: 0x105848600>) more than once which is not supported and is most likely an error in the application : xxx'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`