# iOS webView swipe left or right to navigate

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swipe-gesture

I'm making a simple webView iOS 7 app and I would like the user to be able to swipe left or right to go forward or backward on webpages. Just like you can do in safari in iOS.

I think it is called pagination — but I have no idea how to use it. How can I implement this? I'm a noob so if you could tell me step by step I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: WHAT IS THE CONTENT IN WEBVIEW HTML OR PDF ?

Comment: Consider using a `UINavigationController`. It already supports swiping left-to-right out of the box, so you just need to add support for swiping in the opposite direction. This answer should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891432/swipe-back-and-forward-on-navigationcontroller

Answer (score 9):

I'm working on a similar feature in an app of mine, and here's what I've figured out so far - I'm not done yet, but here's a way to get started.

First, I'm assuming you're developing for iOS 7 only - while it's totally possible to build this for iOS 6, you can take a couple of neat shortcuts if you're only developing for 7.

The forward/backward gestures are handled with a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`. You add it to the web view like so:

```
    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeBack:)];
bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer];

UIView *invisibleScrollPreventer = [UIView new];
invisibleScrollPreventer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:invisibleScrollPreventer];
```

That'll add the back-swipe gesture. The tricky part is that invisibleScrollPreventer - it's an imperfect hack, but it'll avoid scrolling your web view instead of doing the back action. (There's probably a better way to handle that, but that's my current solution.)

In your `swipeBack:` method, you'll do something like the following:

```
-(void)swipeBack:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (_webView.canGoBack) {
            [_webView goBack];
        }
    }
}
```

You'd do these same things to add a `goForward:` method to your web view.

The *real* trick is getting the web page that you're going back to (or forward to) to appear onscreen as you're swiping back or forward, as in Safari in iOS 7. I'm not 100% sure how to do this (I haven't built that function yet in my app, but I will soon) and I'm guessing it's an iOS 7 [snapshotView](https://coderwall.com/p/56wcfq) with some darkening applied.

Depending on how you choose to build this, you may also want to check out [custom navigation transitions in iOS 7](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/). I don't know if that's required for this problem, but it might be.

Good luck!

Comment: OK thank you! I should know this, but where do I put these code snippets? .m or .h?

Comment: All of that code would go in your .m file - if you're confused on a .h vs a .m file, check out this Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619048/concise-description-of-how-h-and-m-files-interact-in-objective-c

Comment: What is the delegate for?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
var webView: WKWebView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://yourwebsite.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true  //so easy!
    }

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.whatever.com")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj)



    //swipe left or right to go back or foward 
    var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))

    leftSwipe.direction = .Left
    rightSwipe.direction = .Right

    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)


}



//swipe left to go forward
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .Left) {
        myWebView.goForward()

    }
//swipe right to go backward
    if (sender.direction == .Right) {
         myWebView.goBack()

    }


}
```

Comment: Replace the quote character with `"` in `NSURL(string:)` constructor (that will fix code highlighting).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).